# Get the newest and the second newest date per value in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0d80c48bd048ab24f39b5172c348c785)**

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    event_date DATE,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    sales_volume VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO sales
(event_date, campaign, sales_volume)
VALUES 
('2020-01-01', 'C001', '125'),
('2020-01-02', 'C001', '300'),
('2020-01-07', 'C001', '700'),
('2020-01-12', 'C001', '900'),

('2020-01-08', 'C002', '600'),
('2020-01-10', 'C002', '465'),
('2020-02-15', 'C002', '570'),
('2020-03-22', 'C002', '780'),

('2020-02-01', 'C003', '150'),
('2020-03-17', 'C003', '325'),
('2020-03-18', 'C003', '482'),
('2020-04-19', 'C003', '323');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
campaign  |   event_date    |  
----------|-----------------|---
  C001    |   2020-01-07    |  
  C001    |   2020-01-12    |     
----------|-----------------|---
  C002    |   2020-02-15    |
  C002    |   2020-03-22    |
----------|-----------------|---
  C003    |   2020-03-18    |
  C003    |   2020-04-19    |
```

---

In the results I want to extract the **newest** and the **second newest** `event_date` for each campaign. 
So far I am able to get the **newest** `event_date` with this query:

```
SELECT
campaign AS campaign,
MAX(s.event_date) AS event_date
FROM sales s
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

How do I need to modify the query to also get the **second newest** `event_date`?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you should never store numbers in `varchar` columns. `sales_volume` should be an `integer`, `bigint` or `numeric` . Also: the limit of 255 does not magically make this more efficient compare to a limit of 258 or 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to achieve this

```
select *
from (
  select campaign, 
         event_date, 
         sales_volume,
         dense_rank() over (partition by campaign order by event_date desc) as rnk
  from sales
) t
where rnk <= 2
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=402d73203d5f9f3de169ca55d65a1fd7)

Comment: Just for my documentation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c3cec4280f2c707434e126fdc4ae3fc4

Comment: @Michi: there is no need to use GROUP BY here